# Do you need less force to pick same mass having greater surface area comparison to other?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, pressure

Suppose a object having mass 10kg and surface area of 2cm² and another other object having same mass and surface area of 4cm². What is the pressure required to lift the object? Which one will need more force to lift the object and how surface area relates in term of lifting the object?

Comment: Hint: same mass means same force.

Comment: Lesser surface area will be a problem in lifting due to less area available for making friction force. But the vertical force is just the same

Comment: @Physiker does surface area which is related to pressure play no role in lifting an object?

Comment: @Proscionexium means friction force only applies Horizontally , while lifting a object. Will it affect total force exerted to lift the object.

Comment: Friction call apply in any direction but only opposite to the relative motion. Here you need the weight equal to mg to lift the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need the same force to pick up the object regardless of its surface area, because you are lifting a mass in a force field, and mass does not depend on any geometrical properties the object may have. Pressure, however, is defined as $P=\frac{F}{S}$ and therefore you would need twice as much pressure to lift an object with half the other's surface. If you want to expand on this subject, I recommend Pearson's University Physics Volume I, which covers Classical (Newtonian) Mechanics with some mentions to pressure, if I remember correctly